# Can I replay levels in Hi-Fi Rush?

Tags: hi-fi-rush

I missed some collectables in a stage and want to go back to get them. Is there a way to replay a stage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can replay old stages, but you have to finish the game first.

According to [Gamerant](https://gamerant.com/hi-fi-rush-how-to-replay-levels-stage-select-track/):

> It is possible to replay levels in Hi-Fi Rush, though players must first unlock level select.
> Players that are interested in replaying levels should focus their efforts on beating Hi-Fi Rush. It is at that point that players will receive indication that they have unlocked several new gameplay mechanics, **one of which is level select**.
> Once level select has been unlocked, fans can simply interact with the hideout's sofa in order to engage with this new feature.